# Map whole list in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I want to be able to do smth like this

```
List(1, 2, 3).someFunc?(list => List(list, list)) // List(List(1,2,3), List(1,2,3))
```

The general idea is I want smth like `map`, but acting not on the elements of the list, but on the whole list itself. Alternative is to write smth like this:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3)
val res = List(list, list)
```

But I'd like some function that could be used in chains. Is there a function like this?

EDIT:
Ideally I'd like to chain map over elements and this "kind of map" for the whole list interchangably, e.g.

```
 List(1, 2, 3).map(_ + 1).someFunc?(list => List(list, list))
```

Comment: `.map` is applied to every element in the data structure, not the data structure itself.

Comment: if you want to apply a function to a value, why don't use the 'normal' `fun(value)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily define your own operator:

```
implicit class RichList[T](l: List[T]){
  def applyFun[U](f: List[T] => U): U = f(l)
}
```

You can even add some restriction on the output type of the function that can be applied, eg if you want to make sure that the output is still a list (just replace `U` with `List[U]` as the output of `f` and the output of `applyFun[U]`).

Comment: From all the answers this one seems the most practical to me. Although I was hoping that there's some built-in method in List for doing this

Comment: this is not specific to the nature of lists, you just want to apply a function on an object (here a list, but it could be anything), using postfix notation.

Comment: Yep, it's not, I meant to say, that it would be cool if this was already a feature of scala.lang, rather than I need to write this implicit class

Answer (score 1):

I think an option suits your needs well:

```
Option(List(1, 2, 3)).map(lst => List(lst, lst))
```

You may also want to consider streams:

```
Stream.continually(List(1, 2, 3)).take(2).toList
```

You can then map over this list of lists however you want.

Comment: It looks like an overkill to me wrapping List in another Monad just to make this kind of transformation. Not mentioning the fact that it will be hard to map over the elements of this list in this case (ideally I'd like to chain these interchangably)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a pattern matching here:

```
List(1, 2, 3) match { case x => List(x, x) }
// res25: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2, 3))
```